# Error Office.Interop.Word on Windows Server 2019

Tags: c#, .net, ms-word, office-interop, windows-server-2019

I have a problem with .NET app, where application not working correct  on the Windows Server 2019. Problem is in using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word library. On the server is installed and activated Office 2019 and Word run normally.
The interesting thing is that if I start application as console application with exe file, so everything runs and process is completed correct, but if I try to run the application with Task Scheduler or i changed application to Windows Service, so application return exception. Exception occurs in the moment, when the application trying create or add a document Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application.Documents.Add(...).

I used the same processes (application) on older Windows Servers with MS Office and everything runned correctly without exceptions.

Do you have idea, where can by a problem? Some permissions?

I tried different steps and configuration, but not working.
For example I created folders "Desktop" in
C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\config\systemprofile

or I changed basic permissions Office DCOM in Component Services. But nothing helps.

Thanks a lot.

Exception:

**System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80010105): The server threw an exception. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010105 (RPC_E_SERVERFAULT))**

Code:

```
appWord = new Application();
appWord.Visible = true;
wordDocument = appWord.Documents.Add(Template: Path.GetFullPath(...), Visible: false);
appWord.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 3):

> if I try to run the application with Task Scheduler or i changed application to Windows Service, so application return exception

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution.

Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2) article.

As a possible workaround you may consider using the [Open XML SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/open-xml-sdk) if you deal with open XML documents only. Otherwise, you may take a look at third-party components designed for the server-side execution.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
I know it, that Microsoft Office library doesn't support server-side actions, but in the past everything working fine and still works for other projects. OpenXML I am already using, but this library can't export documents from DOCX to PDF a this is a main problem. I am currently using Microsoft Office library for this action. I will trying found another solution.